# Excel VBA Autofill trouble

Tags: vba, excel

I want to autofill a formula down to the last row.
If I only choose one column it works fine but if I select a larger range containing both rows and columns the function doesn't fill the first row or the first column. Anyone know why?

The first code snippet works like it is supposed to:

```
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("V1")) Is Nothing Then
    wsPlan.Range("V4").Formula = "=IFERROR(INDEX(Data!$I:$I,MATCH(VALUE(ROW()&V$2),Data!$A:$A,0)),"""")"
    Range("V4").AutoFill Destination:=Range("V4:V" & Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
End If
```

The second omits column V and row 4, any ideas why?

```
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("V1")) Is Nothing Then
    wsPlan.Range("V4").Formula = "=IFERROR(INDEX(Data!$I:$I,MATCH(VALUE(ROW()&V$2),Data!$A:$A,0)),"""")"
    Range("V4").AutoFill Destination:=Range("V4:X" & Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
End If
```

Comment: Where is this code? Module or worksheet code sheet? why do you specify wsPlan in one line and not the other?

Comment: The code is in the worksheet so it refers to the same cells. I will update them so both are the same in the code, thanks.

Comment: Using the AutoFill it works as if you're using the corner of the cell in Excel to fill, and doesn't like two way fill. It's columns or rows and not both combined unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write all of the formulas at once. AutoFill doesn't handle a two direction fill very well.

```
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("V1")) Is Nothing Then
    with wsPlan
        'write all of the formulas into V:X
        .Range(.cells(4, "V"), .cells(.rows.count, "E").end(xlup).offset(0, 19)).Formula = _
            "=IFERROR(INDEX(Data!$I:$I, MATCH(VALUE(ROW()&V$2), Data!$A:$A, 0)), text(,))"
    end with
End If
```

Comment: Thank you, for the clarification.
Your solution works very well but I ended up using two Autofills as that felt faster.